# Как вывести блок за пределы родительского. CSS

Tags: html, css

Привет!
Есть вопрос.
Например имеем родительского блок.
В нем есть дочерний.
Как вывести этот блок за пределы?

Код:

```css
#blok1 {
    margin: 100px 100px;
  width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}
#blok2 {
  width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="blok1">
    <div id="blok2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю можно задать дочернему блоку минимальную ширину больше, чем у родителя. Мне это понадобилось как раз в ситуации, когда контент должен был выходить за рамки.

Answer (score 4):

Абсолютное позиционирование либо относительно родителя, либо относительно документа.
Пример смещения относительно родителя:
http://jsfiddle.net/QrWSX/22/

```css
#blok1 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px 100px;
  width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}
#blok2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
  width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="blok1">
    <div id="blok2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `position:absolute;`
   Указав координаты   `top` || `bottom`, `left` || `right` можно задать любую позицию блока относительно родителя.
2. Использовать отрицательный `margin`

Comment: 1.это если один блок. а если на странице таких блоков 10? что тогда делать? для каждого блока отдельно писать?
2. спасибо. я тупанул ..

Comment: Вы, как-нибудь, четче ставьте задачу, а то не очень понятно, что Вам нужно

Comment: @V_Pavelov, а если их много и absolute'ом спозиционировать нельзя, то стоит задуматься, то ли ты делаешь.

Answer (score 1):

`position:relative;`

```css
#blok1 {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

#blok2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  top:-100px;
  left:-100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="blok1">
  <div id="blok2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задать выезжающему элементу [`overflow: visible`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow).